# Save python random forest model to file

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

In R, after running "random forest" model, I can use `save.image("***.RData")` to store the model. Afterwards, I can just load the model to do predictions directly.

Can you do a similar thing in python? I separate the Model and Prediction into two files. And in Model file:

```
rf= RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=250, max_features=9,compute_importances=True)
fit= rf.fit(Predx, Predy)
```

I tried to return `rf` or `fit`, but still can't load the model in the prediction file.

Can you separate the model and prediction using the sklearn random forest package?

Comment: Note that R's `save.image` saves everything in your workspace, including datasets, working variables, etc. If you only want the fitted model, use `save`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this useful answer! Bc everytime I save.image, the file should be veryyyy large. Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
...
import cPickle

rf = RandomForestRegresor()
rf.fit(X, y)

with open('path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(rf, f)


# in your prediction file                                                                                                                                                                                                           

with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
    rf = cPickle.load(f)


preds = rf.predict(new_X)
```

Comment: Further question: 'path/to/file', what format should i use to save the file? thanks

Comment: @user3013706 do you mean what file extension? It shouldnt matter. I think the convention is to use `.cpickle`

Comment: The scikit learn docs recommand `joblib.dump`, which also comes in `sklearn.externals.joblib`

Comment: Is this answer still relevant for python3? I see cPickle is now _pickle.

Comment: @lamecicle from what I know, it's just `pickle`, the default implementation should be in `C`.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead Does Pickle  or Joblib stores model with corresponding model wights? How do I scale my new inputs? Shall I also store scalar along with weight and model?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to save and load the Random Forest from scikit-learn (in fact, any model from scikit-learn)

The example:

```py
import joblib
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# create RF
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# fit on some data
rf.fit(X, y)

# save
joblib.dump(rf, "my_random_forest.joblib")

# load
loaded_rf = joblib.load("my_random_forest.joblib")
```

What is more, the `joblib.dump` `has compress` argument, so the model can be compressed. I made very simple [test](https://mljar.com/blog/save-load-random-forest/) on iris dataset and `compress=3` reduces the size of the file about 5.6 times.

Comment: joblib.save is joblib.dump

Answer (score 2):

I use dill, it stores all the data and I think possibly module information? Maybe not. I remember trying to use `pickle` for storing these really complicated objects and it didn't work for me.  `cPickle` probably does the same job as `dill` but i've never tried `cpickle`. it looks like it works in literally the exact same way.  I use "obj" extension but that's by no means conventional...It just made sense for me since I was storing an object.

```
import dill
wd = "/whatever/you/want/your/working/directory/to/be/"
rf= RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=250, max_features=9,compute_importances=True)
rf.fit(Predx, Predy)
dill.dump(rf, open(wd + "filename.obj","wb"))
```

btw, not sure if you use iPython, but sometimes writing a file that way doesn't so you  have to do the:

```
with open(wd + "filename.obj","wb") as f:
    dill.dump(rf,f)
```

call the objects again:

```
model = dill.load(open(wd + "filename.obj","rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

for the model storing you can also use .sav formate. it stores complete model and information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reiterate that joblib does the job well and [it provides really good compression options](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/compressors_comparison.html#comparing-the-results) (ie lzma).

```
with open("clf.pkl", "wb") as out: pickle.dump(clf, out)
with open("clf.dill", "wb") as out: dill.dump(clf, out)
joblib.dump(clf, "clf.jbl")
joblib.dump(clf, "clf.jbl.lzma")
joblib.dump(clf, "clf.jbl.gz")

!du clf.*
24576   clf.dill
24576   clf.jbl
5120    clf.jbl.gz
3072    clf.jbl.lzma
24576   clf.pkl
```