# how to give input to loaded .pkl model in python

Tags: python, input, pickle, random-forest, test-data

I have a Random Forest model, and model saved in .pkl file.
I have loaded the .pkl model but now I have to input the test data and predict the accuracy.
how to input file to .pkl model?

```
import pickle

def read_from_pickle(RF):
    with open(RF, 'rb') as file:
        try:
            while True:
                yield pickle.load(file)
        except EOFError:
            pass
```

this is the code i have used to load the model
Next..how to input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save python random forest model to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662023/save-python-random-forest-model-to-file)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is with random Forrest regressor my model was dynamic price prediction

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import pipeline, preprocessing,metrics,model_selection,ensemble,linear_model
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

// firstly we loaded this library and then we loaded the dataset and all the cleaning stuff we did after that

data.to_csv("Pune_hpp.csv",index=False)

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
(['area_type','size','new_total_sqft','bath','balcony',], preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
# (['area_type','size'],preprocessing.OneHotEncoder())

```
                    ],df_out=True)
```

// hear we created two pipeline  for it bcz we have compared two algorithm with mse and rsme method and loaded the this below algo

pipeline_obj_LR=pipeline.Pipeline([
('mapper',mapper),
("model",linear_model.LinearRegression())
])

pipeline_obj=pipeline.Pipeline([
('mapper',mapper),
("model",ensemble.RandomForestRegressor())
])

X=['area_type','size','new_total_sqft','bath','balcony']  // X with INPUT

Y=['price'] // Y as OUTPUT

// hear the comparison process start

pipeline_obj_LR.fit(data[X],data[Y])   // this logistic regression

pipeline_obj.fit(data[X],data[Y])     // random forest

pipeline_obj.predict(data[X])      // some predict we have done

predict=pipeline_obj_LR.predict(data[X])

//BELLOW is the actual way to compare and which algo is best fited

predict=pipeline_obj_LR.predict(data[X])

## Root Mean Squared Error on train and test data

print('MSE using linear_regression: ', mean_squared_error(data[Y], predict))
print('RMSE using linear_regression: ', mean_squared_error(data[Y], predict)**(0.5))

// above is for the lr

predict=pipeline_obj.predict(data[X])

## Root Mean Squared Error on train and test data

print('MSE using randomforestregression: ', mean_squared_error(data[Y], predict))
print('RMSE using randomforestregression: ', mean_squared_error(data[Y], predict)**(0.5))

// above it is for RFR and in my I have done with the random forest reason to do with the joblib was I had the huge dataset and it easy to implement and it's line of code also very less and you have seen I have not use the pipeline_obj_LR  this how we have inputed the value in pkl file

import joblib

joblib.dump(pipeline_obj,'dynamic_price_pred.pkl')

modelReload=joblib.load('dynamic_price_pred.pkl')

Comment: The answer is not formatted properly, code is written as text